# Migrations Inside of Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, auto-increment

Earlier today I signed up for a nettuts plus account and have been watching this series on codeigniter cms building. I am creating a migration file to create my users table. With my user ids I prefer to work with user ids that look like this `10000` and increment to `10001` for the next inserted user. What I'm trying to figure out was how do I setup so that when it creates the users table then to have the key start at `10000`

https://tutsplus.com/course/build-a-cms-in-codeigniter/

After looking around I am not able to find out how to accomplish this. If anyone knows please help me out.

Comment: https://github.com/AimalAzmi/codeigniter-migrations

Try this, I've written a library for this which can be used very easily through the CLI. It can be used to create migrations files and run migrations backwards or forwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I didn't watch the videos). After you create your table run this SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

Change `tablename` to the table name

Comment: Thank you for the edit of tags for my post. Any idea how this could be accomplished inside of the CI migrations so that I as a user don't have to go in and change it manually just in case I pass this off as a project for testing on another server?

Comment: I just looked through the documentation and didn't see a method to do this. I'm wondering if this would require running a regular query to work?

Comment: I mean I could but now I'm interested in seeing if it does allow you to somehow.